# Polynomial and exponential regression

Tags: polynomials, regression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determining computational complexity of stochastic processes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103555/determining-computational-complexity-of-stochastic-processes)

I have some points $(x_i,y_i)$ generated by a program. These values are not exact, but are random fluctuations around an average value (though quite close, I think). I want to know whether $y(x)=O(e^x)$ or $y(x)=O( poly \,\, x)$. Does anyone know how, and to what degree of certainty, this distinction is possible?

Note: This question is an alternative formulation of my question [Determining computational complexity of stochastic processes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103555/determining-computational-complexity-of-stochastic-processes).